# how to write a query that returns the second quarter of a year .....example total profit of second quarter from 2011 to 2016

Tags: sql, postgresql

```sql
SELECT SUM(profit),
DATE_PART('quarter',2,sales_date) AS Quarter,sales_year
FROM sales_data
GROUP BY sales_year,sales_date
```

this is what i have tried

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant, and e.g. DATE_PART is a product specific function.)

Comment: What RDBMS are you *really* using? `DATE_PART` isn't a valid T-SQL function, so I *assume* it's PostgreSQL, not SQL Server. Of course, if you *are* using SQL Server, then the above will error. You haven't explained why what you've tried doesn't work so we don't know the reason why it isn't. Also, grouping on `sales_date` when you want each group by its quarter is likely your problem here; your data is going to be grouped by each date, not each date's quarter (and year).

Comment: Doesn't do any good to group by sales_date - that gives you one row per date. You need to group by the same value as in your "Quarter" expression in the select list - which should be using DATEPART if using SQL Server.

Comment: i am using pgadmin4

Comment: okay i do you suggest i write a query to return for the second quarter of a given data set

Comment: @abdulazeez PGAdmin is a web interface for interacting with PostgreSQL; it isn't an actual RDBMS.

Comment: @larnu what do you suggest i do

Comment: Assuming that PostgreSQL works the same way as SQL Server, then fix your `GROUP BY` clause; you're grouping by each individual date, not the date's quarter.

Comment: There is no version of `date_part()` in Postgres that accepts three parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a WHERE clause that only selects dates from the second quarter, then you need to GROUP BY the quarter, not the full date.

```
select sales_year, 
       date_part('quarter', sales_date) as quarter,
       sum(profit)
from sales_data
where date_part('quarter', sales_date) = 2 -- get only dates from second quarter
   and sales_date >= date '2011-01-01'
   and sales_date  < date '2017-01-01' -- only from 2011 to 2016
group by sales_year, date_part('quarter', sales_date)
```

Comment: this worked, thank you so much I really appreciate

Comment: thank you all for your for contribution